# One Tomcat two spring application (war) two seperate logging configurations

Tags: spring, logging, configuration, log4j, logback

As mentioned in the title I have two applications with two different logging configurations. As soon as I use springs logging.file setting I can not seperate the configurations of both apps.

The problem worsens because one app is using logback.xml and one app is using log4j.properties.

I tried to introduce a new configuration parameter in one application where I can set the path to the logback.xml but I am unable to make the new setting work for all logging in the application.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    reconfigureLogging();
    SpringApplication.run(IndexerApplication.class, args);
}

private static void reconfigureLogging() {
    if (System.getProperty("IndexerLogging") != null && !System.getProperty("IndexerLogging").isEmpty()) {
        try {
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
            configurator.setContext(context);
            // Call context.reset() to clear any previous configuration, e.g. default
            // configuration. For multi-step configuration, omit calling context.reset().
            System.out.println("SETTING: " + System.getProperty("IndexerLogging"));
            System.out.println("SETTING: " + System.getProperty("INDEXER_LOG_FILE"));
            context.reset();
            configurator.doConfigure(System.getProperty("IndexerLogging"));

        } catch (JoranException je) {
            System.out.println("FEHLER IN CONFIG");

        }
        logger.info("Entering application.");
    }
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    reconfigureLogging();
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}
```

The above code works somehow. But the only log entry which is written to the logfile specified in the configuration, which ${IndexerLogging} points to, is the entry from logger.info("Entering application."); :(

I don't really like to attach that code to every class which does some logging in the application.

The application has to be runnable as tomcat deployment but also as spring boot application with integrated tomcat use.

Any idea how I can set the path from ${IndexerLogging} as the path to read the configuration file when first configuring logging in that application?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-extensions/wiki/Spring you can configure the logback config file to use.